# Need to Force Email Action in Case Feed to be HTML Only

Tags: visualforce, case

I've looked at [Customizing the Email Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.case_feed_dev.meta/case_feed_dev/case_feed_dev_guide_email_publisher.htm), and written this simple page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
  <apex:emailPublisher entityId="{!case.id}" emailBodyFormat="HTML" />
</apex:page>
```

Would I need anything else to accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: We can only track if an email is opened if it was sent in HTML, which the Email Action within Case Feed doesn't allow.  We want all emails to default to HTML only from the Case Feed so we can track if they are opened or not by the contact.